# I call Alert.Show in a function and want to get the result from there (Flex, ActionScript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm using the Alert.show in a function and I want to get the user answer from there. So how can I achieve this. The problem is the function that call Alert.show will return a true or false value depend the user answer.
but It seem that in Alert.show it only allow to pass in a CloseHandler for this. that is a new function. and since that I can get the user answer from where it is call to return the user answer.

Really thanks for help
Yuan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Simple example to demonstrate the Halo Alert control. -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;

            // Event handler function uses a static method to show
            // a pop-up window with the title, message, and requested buttons.
            private function clickHandler(evt:Event):void {
                Alert.show("Do you want to save your changes?", "Save Changes", Alert.YES|Alert.NO, this, alertClickHandler);
            }

            // Event handler function for displaying the selected Alert button.
            private function alertClickHandler(evt:CloseEvent):void {
                if (evt.detail == Alert.YES) {
                    status.text = "You answered Yes";
                } else {
                    status.text = "You answered No";
                }
            }

            // Event handler function changes the default Button labels and sets the
            // Button widths. If you later use an Alert with the default Buttons, 
            // you must reset these values.
            private function secondClickHandler(evt:Event):void {
                Alert.buttonWidth = 100;
                Alert.yesLabel = "Magenta";
                Alert.noLabel = "Blue";
                Alert.cancelLabel = "Green";

                Alert.show("Select a color:", "Color Selection", Alert.YES|Alert.NO|Alert.CANCEL, this);

                // Set the labels back to normal:
                Alert.yesLabel = "Yes";
                Alert.noLabel = "No";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Panel title="Halo Alert Control Example"
            width="75%"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
            <s:Label color="blue"
                    text="Click the button below to display a simple Alert window."/>
            <s:Button label="Click Me" click="Alert.show('Hello World!', 'Message');"/>

            <mx:HRule width="100%" />

            <s:Label color="blue" 
                    text="Click the button below to display an Alert window and capture the button pressed by the user."/>
            <s:Button label="Click Me" click="clickHandler(event);"/>
            <s:Label id="status" fontWeight="bold"/>

            <mx:HRule width="100%" />

            <s:Label color="blue"
                    text="Click the button below to display an Alert window that uses custom Button labels."/>
            <s:Button label="Click Me" click="secondClickHandler(event);"/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.
here's how:

```
private function deleteItem_Confirmation_Handler(event:CloseEvent):void
    {
        if(event.detail == Alert.OK)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }

    public function deleteValue():void
    {
        Alert.show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", "confimation", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, null, deleteItem_Confirmation_Handler, null, Alert.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, But in this code I can't get the user answer to return to the function that call deleteValue().
It seem that Alert.show() cannot get user answer from where is it call http://flexed.wordpress.com/2006/08/04/alertshow-behavour-in-flex/

Comment: @Yuan, you can pass an anonymus function to the Alert.show call like in event listeners look at example here: http://www.kensodev.com/2009/07/14/add-a-parameter-or-even-more-then-one-to-flex-event-listener/ this shown event listener but Alert.show is the same. Keep in mind, it is not best practice at all

Answer (score 0):

change

```
evt.detail == Alert.YES
```

to

```
evt.detail == 1
```

the yes button returns an int value of 1, the no button would return an int value of 2